# Can FlasCC and Haxe be used together?

Tags: flash, haxe, flascc

This is a rookie question as I'm very new to Haxe and have no experience with FlasCC (the C compiler for Flash).

Is it possible to use FlasCC and Haxe together, to bring the performance improvements of both technologies together to Flash?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the way you want to use it together(but you probably might, by making swc in FlasCC and using from haxe).

However, it is pointless as it wont give you any performance benefits, and most likely will make your code slower than pure haxe. Haxe does pretty good job on making fast AVM2(flash virtual machine) bytecode. Some small and tricky things can still be optimized, but not by means of FlasCC. I work with haxe=>flash for years and I thoroughly explored a lot of bytecode it generates, sometimes I was able to speed it up a bit, but only by direct editing of bytecode(read: I wrote a simple disassembler and assembler, and used assembler patches on bytecode after haxe generated it).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will notice huge performance boost.

Because C++ code generated by Haxe/OpenFL, it not super optimized.

I don't think that it's worth effort.

You can get top performance using Stage3D for graphics and using openfl.flash.Memory for per pixel operations and some data/caching processing.